# Angular unit test file upload input - DataTransfer is undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

Trying to write a Jest unit test for a file upload input element.

Based on what i've found online, I'm trying to mock selecting a file by programmatically setting the files attribute on the input element like so:

```
  function selectFile(inputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    const mockFile = new File(['Hello World'], 'test-file.txt');
    dataTransfer.items.add(mockFile);
    inputElement.files = dataTransfer.files;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change'));
    return fixture.whenStable();
  }
```

However I just receive the error that "DataTransfer is not defined".

Is there something I'm missing here? Why is DataTransfer undefined? Or how else am I supposed to mock selecting a file for a unit test with Jest?

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356093/how-to-write-the-unit-testing-for-the-file-upload-method-in-the-angular-7-or-2) I found for reference.
[Here](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/8994) is another post of someone else using Jest and having the same issue. But the incident was closed without any resolution.

Comment: you can just set the 'value' attribute of the <input type="file"> element to the path of your file and submit the form.  (You should use full absolute path to the file.)  DataTransfer sounds like something that would come from drag or copy/paste event.